# Recommended layout for Ruby CLI application

Tags: ruby, architecture, command-line-interface

Firstly, I'm not using rails. This is vanilla ruby application. I've read about [packaging a CLI ruby application as a GEM](http://www.acmesprockets.com/node/24).

So I guess my question would be, is this the ruby way? Does this layout lend itself to class autoloading?

I'm coming from a PHP background where I'm used to application layouts that adhere to [PSR-0](https://gist.github.com/1234504) style (see examples section).

Comment: How big is this program? Small little utilities are usually one file, while larger programs are broken into a `/bin`, a `/lib`, and sometimes a `/ext`. Autoloading classes is going out of style, and is something that you shouldn't do without good reason. Just `require` the class you need.

Comment: Also, gems are libraries, and command line scripts should only be included if they have something to do with managing the library (e.g. a database generator script for a database library). If this is an end user application of some sort, a gem is the wrong thing.

Comment: The application will be larger than a single file. I plan to publish my blog to static pages rather than have dynamically generated pages ala rails. Purely for performance as I run on a VPS with minimal resources. Why is autoloading going out of fashion? Any justification? I read it's not thread safe to use `autoload` but I don't plan to use threads. Thanks for the advice. Steering clear of a GEM layout.

Comment: The thing is, if I know that I need the class in `foo.rb`, I would just require `foo.rb`. Autoloading is more like a lazy load (think lazy construction). If I have a class that is only necessary if I call `rarely_used_method`, I could autoload the class to avoid polluting the namespace and memory footprint. I think that is what autoload is for.

Comment: Fair enough, I can see how classes that require a method from a module will always need to require that module ... I guess it's more a taste/opinion thing. If the code is refactored and dependencies change autoloading may solve some rework of `require` statements, and can benefit from lazy loading as you've stated. I'll run with require for now and see how I get on. static `require` and `include` calls have just died a death in recent years in PHP.

Comment: @Linux_iOS, as a tangent to the current discussion, could you please elaborate on why gems are not appropriate for end-user applications? I ask because I have a ruby CLI application I've been developing mostly for my personal use that I decided to release as a gem.

Comment: Also, `require` is a regular method itself and you can take advantage of that to implement lazy loading. For example, if you have a method that is not used often and depends on an external module, you can require it in that method instead of at the top of the file, thus loading the module precisely when it is actually needed. Note that this will add an extra overhead, as ruby will check if the module has already been loaded every time the method is called.

Comment: Well, gems are for libraries, right? Actually, you are right that that would be a great idea. Never thought of that, thanks!

Comment: So the linked article on CLI apps as a Ruby GEM is a "good thing"? Was concerned about absolute paths and `require` but I've just read about $LOAD_PATH. Thanks for the info so far.

Comment: Yesterday I stumbled across Jekyll that seems to be 85% of what I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way to build and distribute a Ruby command-line app is more or less as that article describes:

- `bin` - exe goes here
- `lib/your_app.rb` - requires all files under `lib/your_app`
- `lib/your_app/whatever.rb` - modules and files to build your command-line app
- `your_app.gemspec` - gemspec; make sure you mention that there's a bin file
- `Rakefile` - manage development
- `test` - yup, tests

It's completely OK to break up your app into classes and modules inside `lib`.  By distributing with RubyGems the command-line app will be in the user's path and it will have access to everything in `lib`.

RubyGems has first-class support for distributing command-line apps; it's not just for libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can execute any ruby file from command-line interface (CLI) using [console_runner](https://github.com/yuri-karpovich/console_runner) gem. All you need is to add annotations ([YARD](https://yardoc.org/)-like syntax) to your Ruby code and then execute it from command line:

```
$ c_run /path/your_file.rb say_hello
```

**/path/your_file.rb**:

```
# @runnable
class MyClass

    # @runnable
    def say_hello
      puts 'Hello!'
    end

end
```